# Unreal Engine 5 Groom Hair Explodes

Tags: game-physics, particle-system, unreal-engine5

Hello I am trying to get a Hairparticlesystem I made as a test in Blender to work in Unreal Engine 5 as a groom asset.

So far I am very confused and I think it might have something to do with the different scalings in Unreal engine compared to blender but I don't know what seems to be the real issue here

Whenever I import the alembic for the groom asset according to the tutorials setting with the scale of the export in blender to **100** it resizes the hair to be gigantic so I set it to a normal **1**.

**It seems to look right visually but as soon as I move the character and the physics kick in the whole system spazzes out.**

[Video of Hair going crazy](https://youtu.be/0DnXkQcWpGg)

Can something with the physics asset of the mesh mess with it?

What am I doing wrong? did I misunderstand something fundamental here?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if anybody cares but for what its worth, it turned out to be an issue with the physics asset. The collisioncapsule was way bigger than the head. That cause it to spazz out.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to change groom hair settings under: Material Constraints> Collision Constraint> Collision radius from default of 8 to something like 0.5 (or whichever number works). The default value of 8 is too large and causes the hair to explode.